# Appending elements - stop appending when elements starts to overflow the container

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

Im trying to sort out a "board" where you can add elements in various sizes using masonry, and im trying to figure out how to stop the possibility to append new elements if the container is full and elements starts to overflow it.

The code:

HTML

```
<input id="width" value="0" type="text"></input>
<input id="height" value="0" type="text"></input>
<input id="mLeft" value="0" type="text"></input>
<input id="mRight" value="0"type="text"></input>
<button>Add container</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var $pWidth = jQuery("#width").val();
    var $truePWidth = $pWidth * 15;
    var $pHeight = jQuery("#height").val();
    var $truePHeight = $pHeight * 15;
    var $mLeft = jQuery("#mLeft").val();
    var $trueMLeft = $mLeft * 15;
    var $mRight = jQuery('#mRight').val();
    var $trueMRight = $mRight * 15;
    $container.append("<div class='box'><div class='remove'></div></div>").masonry( 'reload', function(){
           $(".box").each(function(i) {
                 $(this).attr("id", "item"+(i+1));
            });
        $($container).children('.box:last-child').css({'height' : $truePHeight + 'px', 'width': $truePWidth + 'px', 'margin-right' : $trueMRight + 'px', 'margin-left' : $trueMLeft + 'px' });
        $container.masonry( 'reload');
    } );

});
```

The container(var $container = #container), where the elements (.box) are added is 1600px high.

Thanks in advance!

/Jonas

Comment: Does your need to cut them off come from not wanting it to overflow (as in screw up the layout) or from wanting to set a max number of adds?

Comment: As you see in the code i have a click event on the button that adds new elements. What I want to do is to disable the button when the container is full. Right now im just using overflow: hidden;, but that doesn't really solve it, it just hides them.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize. I'm on my phone so I can't do code but you could simply set the CSS for the container as follows:

```
.box {
     max-height: 1600px;
     overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

This will give the container a scroll bar instead of expanding the height of the container while still allowing your users to append an unlimited amount of boxes.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn´t clear. As mentioned in my comment above I want to disable the click event (that appends new elements) when the container is full.